# Android:Text in searchView disappears on Configuration Change

Tags: android, configuration

The text i enter in searchView disappears on config change.
I am already handling the config change but still its not working.
As i have used fragments, so below code is written inside fragment.
Please solve my problem with respect to that.
My problem is i am not able to retrieve savedInstance in onActivityCreated method
Below is my code:
Snippets of useful code

```
private String searchQuery="";

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            if(savedInstanceState != null)
            searchQuery = savedInstanceState.getString(Tag.SEARCH_QUERY);
        }

          @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putString(Tag.SEARCH_QUERY, searchQuery);

        }

 @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater menuInflater) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
            MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
            SearchView searchView = null;
            if (menuItem != null)
                searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();

            if (searchView != null) {
                searchView.setQuery(searchQuery,false);
                searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                        //searching is done in async task
                        searchQuery = query;
                        NetworkUtility.onProgressBarShow(getActivity());
                        MyAsyncTaskDownloadDetails myAsyncTaskDownloadDetails = new MyAsyncTaskDownloadDetails();
                        myAsyncTaskDownloadDetails.execute(new String[]{Tag.PLP_URL + query, Tag.PLP,""});
                        return true;
                    }


                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, menuInflater);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** of all you are saving **queryText** in `onQueryTextSubmit` callback which means `searchQuery`will remain empty unless and until user have submitted query for search, so keep that in mind.

**Secondly** try following code. It will work I have tested it.

```
if(searchQuery.length()>0){

    //See this commented code
    //  if(Utils.hasIceCreamSandwich()) {
    //      searchMenuItem.expandActionView();
    //  }else {
    //      MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(searchMenuItem);
    //  }

    MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(menuItem);
    searchView.setQuery(searchQuery, false);
}
```

Comment: but my problem is i am not able to retrieve savedInstance in onActivityCreated method

Comment: I copy/pasted your code in a sample project and it was working for me.Post your activity code, may b something is wrong with Activity